# ffi gem can't load libraries from PATH on windows in ruby > 2.2.5

Tags: ruby, dll, path, ffi

As a starting point, this code works in ruby up to 2.2.5. For newer versions it returns "cannot load such file".

```
require 'ffi'

module DllTest
    extend FFI::Library
    
    ENV['PATH'] = Dir.pwd + '\lib' + ';' + ENV['PATH']
    
    ffi_lib 'bz2'
    attach_function :version, 'BZ2_bzlibVersion', [], :string
end

puts DllTest.version
```

I run the code from a working directory that has lib folder with bz2.dll in it. The problem is that PATH environment variable is not used. I can specify absolute path to the library and it will work, but there is another problem. I want to use library that loads other libraries which are not in the same directory. I specify that directory in PATH but for some reason it doesn't work. It doesn't matter how I specify the PATH. Whether I do it in console beforehand, or in ruby script like above, I get the error either way.

What I actually want to do is I have library that is installed using 2 gems. The first gem installs core libraries, the second gem installs the actual library that depends on the core libraries. When the library gem is required in ruby, necessary libraries paths are loaded into PATH in a similar way as in the sample code. This worked up to 2.2.5

Any idea why that may be?

---

Even more basic sample, still works only for ruby <2.3:

test.rb:

```
require 'devkit'
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile 'foobar'
`make`
require_relative 'foobar'

ENV['PATH'] = (Dir.pwd + '\lib;').gsub('/', '\\') + ENV['PATH']

load_lib('bz2.dll')
```

foobar.c:

```
#include "ruby.h"

VALUE rb_load_lib(VALUE self, VALUE path)
{
    HMODULE mod;
    printf("%s\n\n", getenv("PATH"));
    mod = LoadLibraryExA(RSTRING_PTR(path), NULL, 0);
    printf("LoadLibraryExA: %s\n", mod != 0 ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL");
    return Qnil;
}

void Init_foobar()
{
    rb_define_global_function("load_lib", rb_load_lib, 1);
}
```

Comment: PATH is used for binaries, why do you think it applies to libraries?

Comment: PATH environment variable is listed in the search order: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications

Comment: In that case you need to determine whether it's windows not loading your libraries or ffi not using PATH like windows does, right?

Comment: I rebuilt the ffi gem C part. It calls LoadLibraryEx (this is the exact function that fails), which supposed to load library and its dependencies using PATH. I inserted print function right before and it does show the directory gets inserted into PATH. I have no idea what else I could check.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with ruby 2.4:

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/wiki/For-gem-developers#-dll-loading

> While the PATH environment variable defines the paths to be searched
> for executables, it is ignored for all DLL searches within the Ruby
> process. Dependent DLLs can instead be loaded by setting the Windows
> DLL search path using the environment variable RUBY_DLL_PATH or by the
> function RubyInstaller::Runtime.add_dll_directory